# What to buy to build a simple robot with Raspberry Pi?

Tags: wifi, camera, raspicam, battery

I live in Pakistan. Here, there is no ebay or amazon so I cannot order things from there. Now tomorrow I am going to shopping out of city and I need some help from the community.

Here's the situation: In this summer vacation I want to build a small wall-e type robot using raspberry pi which would probably be made up from cardboard or something but it would be able to move capture feed from the camera and move his head around and product some sound etc. ( Basically I just want to get myself up and running with robotics )

What I need is a list of things to buy that would work with the raspberry pi.

1) What battery should I purchase to run the raspberry pi?
2) What battery should I purchase to run the whole robot? ( Because DC motors might need more than 3.3 or 5 V )
3) What relay or transistor should I buy that could work with the specific batteries?
4) Which wifi adapter should I buy?
5) Which DC motors are perfect for my projects?
6) Please can anybody tell me what others parts can I buy that could help me with my fun project?

Comment: Why don't you try Ali Express?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Search for something like the [Magician chassis](https://www.sparkfun.com/products/12866).

It comes with a chassis, two wheels, two DC geared motors, and a castor.  Look at the details.  That's the base of what you need.

In addition you will need a motor driver board.  Look for [L298N](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/131276050920) or [L9110S](http://www.ebay.co.uk/itm/301582158434) based boards.

Apart from a battey and an Arduino or the Pi that should be all you need.